# White background is showing above UISearchBar for iOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, ios7

My viewController has a UISearchBar set as the header view of a UITableView.

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
```

In iOS7, pulling down beyond the UISearchBar reveals a white space that does not obey the dark color set using *self.tableView.backgroundColor*.

[image]

Is there a way to get rid of the white space?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I managed to get rid of that color by setting a table view background view.

```
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView;
```

Comment: This works for me: `[self.tableView setBackgroundView:[UIView new]];`

Comment: Swift 4:  `let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView`

Comment: Setting the background color to `.clear` when assigning a new `UIView` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 9):

As developers will likely struggle with the white background in the age of [swift](/questions/tagged/swift):

`tableView.backgroundView = UIView()`

Comment: totally fixed that problem for me. such a simple solution. thanks.

Comment: Working with SWIFT 3

Answer (score 4):

After lots of trial and error, adding a dummy parent UIView to the UISearchBar before setting it as the tableHeaderView prevented the white space from appearing and properly reveals the tableView's background color.

```
UIView *parentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:searchRect];
[parentView addSubview:self.searchBar];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = parentView;
```

Would be interested to see if there are better solutions available.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest enabling the option to Extend Edges in the property inspector of your view